# Why is Twig rejecting this syntax? Throws "Exception: Unexpected "endfor" tag ..."

Tags: php, twig

I am unable to get Twig 'is defined' syntax to work. Here I am iterating through the fields object, and attempting to output text conditionally. Sometimes field will have length set. Other times it will have other attributes. Every variation I can think of using 'is defined' is resulting in an error:
"Exception: Unexpected "endfor" tag (expecting closing tag for the "if" tag..."

I'm following the syntax from the documentation here:
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/defined.html

I can get other conditionals to work without issue. I'm not sure why the endif statement is not being recognized

```
{% for field in fields %}
    {% if field.length is defined %}
            ->setMaxLength({{ field.length }})
    {$ endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am expecting this to recognize the endif statement, and terminate the for loop without throwing exception

Comment: Should `{$ endif %}` be `{% endif %}`?

Comment: umm. no it shouldn't! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was embarrassingly simple. My endif tag had a '$' instead of a '%'. I somehow missed that for ~2hrs. Thanks @Chris White